# Is ghusl mandatory now?

Tags: taharah, ghusl

asalaam alaikum. So my period started on Wednesday the 14th of September and on the 17th it started to stop. This is not usual. Since then i have needed to go to the bathroom more which i find is weird. So on the 19th i start to see white discharge but am also getting yellow and brown discharge with the white. I should not be seeing white discharge this early. Shall i do ghusl or leave it as there is still yellow discharge? Please note that my period has not been very normal concerning this time due to the fact that i have had less blood aswell.